# Getting error code 503 with Rest Assured Post method

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Not sure what the issue is but I am getting an error code 503 with rest assured. Here is the code.

```
 RestAssured.baseURI = "https:XXXXXXXX";
 Response responseObj1;
 String body = "{\"requestId\":\"XXXXX\",\"clientId\":\"XXXX\",\"loyaltyAccountNumber\":\"XXXX\"}";
responseObj1 = given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().header("Content-Type", "application/json").body(body).when()
            .post("XXXXX").then().extract().response();

System.out.println(responseObj1.getStatusCode());
```

Also tried below command

```
responseObj1 = = given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().contentType("application/json")
            .contentType("application/json").
            body("{\"requestId\":\"Request1\",\"clientId\":\"LPE\",\"loyaltyAccountNumber\":\"1M92741392\"}").
            when().
            post("XXXXX");
```

but it is giving me the same error.

Same API works fine in Postman. Any Suggestions, inputs ? Thanks.

Comment: You can add RestAssured.enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails(); before given() and it logs the request.

Comment: Hope there's no certificate or something that needs to be added!

Comment: @Naseem, were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Naseem: I am facing the same issue.Were you able to solve it?